# Custom hook with clear and update time not works as per expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When update the default time with `setInterval`, it's not working as expected. Instead it's added as a new instance. How to clear the `setInterval` in the custom hook and update new value?

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import CustomTimer from './Custom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState(200);

  const time = CustomTimer(intervalTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Hi');
      setIntervalTime(500);
    }, 5000);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some happen! {time} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Custom.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function CustomTimer(startTime) {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(startTime);
  useEffect(() => {
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timer > 0) {
        setTimer(timer - 1);
        console.log(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, [startTime]);
  return timer;
}

export default CustomTimer;
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2pz42z?file=src%2FApp.js) => please check the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results can be tested here as well ==> [Test Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fgkdpp)

First of all, need to add a dependency to the `useEffect` in the `App.js` file since whenever it triggers, the timer starts from the beginning.

**App.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import CustomTimer from './Custom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState(200);
  const time = CustomTimer(intervalTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIntervalTime(500);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);  // Added dependency array here

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some happen! {time} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Custom.js:** (Added comment lines to explain the added/updated lines)

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function CustomTimer(startTime) {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(startTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer(startTime);
    let timerCounter = startTime;

    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timerCounter > 0) {
        // Get the previous state and decrease it 
        setTimer(timer => timer - 1);
        timerCounter--;
        return;
      }

      // Clear interval after timer's work is done
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, [startTime]);

  return timer;
}

export default CustomTimer;
```

Comment: I am find a challenge to reset the interval, on mouse move. can you help?

Comment: @3gwebtrain You can handle it with adding an `event listener` with `mousemove` method and reset timer state to the `startTime` whenever listener triggers. I  configured it in the demo link here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lxmcdp?file=src%2FCustom.js . You can see the event listener in the **Custom.js** file, I also added a comment line there

Comment: It is not resetting to previous value, instead stop the count. pls move your mouse around and observe.

Comment: @3gwebtrain I got it. The counter couldn't be updated so that's the reason for it. Now, I updated the demo link, you can check it here: stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-skulq6. Just added a new state `restartTimer` and updated it whenever the mouse move event is triggered. Also, needed to add it to `useEffect` dependencies to trigger the timer

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

This is the classic stale closure of state in a callback problem, with some additional discrepancies.

- `timer` in the `setInterval` callback is the same value from the initial render cycle, so it always decrements from the same value.
- The `useEffect` hook in `CustomTimer` doesn't "reset" the `timer` state when the `startTime` prop value is changed.
- The `useEffect` hook in `App` is missing a dependency array so it starts a new timeout each render cycle after `intervalTime` is updated the first time.
- `CustomTimer` is really a custom React hook, it should be correctly renamed to `useCustomTimer`.

## Solution

I suggest using a React ref to hold a reference to the current running timer, use a functional state update to enqueue `timer` state updates, and check the current `timer` expiration in a separate `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function useCustomTimer(startTime) {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(startTime);
  const timerRef = useRef();           // <-- ref to hold current timer

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer === 0) {                 // <-- check timer expiration
      console.log("Timer expired");
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    }
  }, [timer])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (startTime > 0) {
      setTimer(startTime);             // <-- reset timer when startTime changes

      timerRef.current = setInterval(
        setTimer,
        1000,
        (timer) => timer - 1           // <-- functional state update
      );
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current); // <-- clear on startTime change or unmount
    }
  }, [startTime]);

  return timer;
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState(200);

  const time = useCustomTimer(intervalTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Hi");
      setIntervalTime(500);
    }, 5000);
  }, []); // <-- add missing dependency array

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen! {time}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit custom-hook-with-clear-and-update-time-not-works-as-per-expected]

## Update to include resetting start time upon `"mousemove"` event

It is trivial to add event listeners to reset the `timer` state. A `"mousemove"` event handler can be added in the `useEffect` with `startTime` as dependency.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (timerRef.current === 0) {
    console.log("Timer expired");
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }
}, [timer]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (startTime > 0) {
    setTimer(startTime);
    timerRef.current = setInterval(
      setTimer,
      1000,
      (timer) => timer - 1
    );
  }

  // Mousemove callback handler
  const handler = () => {
    setTimer(startTime);
  };

  // Instantiate passive mousemove handler
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", handler, true);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    // Remove mousemove handler when startTime changes
    // or component unmounts
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler, true);
  };
}, [startTime]);
```

[image: Edit custom-hook-with-clear-and-update-time-not-works-as-per-expected (forked)]

Comment: I am find a challenge to reset the interval, on mouse move. can you help?

Comment: @3gwebtrain You can use a `useEffect` hook to add/remove a "mousemove" event listener to update/reset any state. Are you basically working on an inactivity timer? This seems extracurricular to the question of this post regarding the interval timer, so it would be better to ask this as a ***new*** post with current details and complete [mcve]. If you create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Hi Drew, here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-with-clear-and-update-time-not-works-as-per-expected-forked-98vmvf please check the console on mouse mouse. getting different values

Comment: @3gwebtrain Thanks for the running sandbox. I have updated my answer here with an improved initial solution, and included an update with the trivial change to add `"mousemove"` event handler to reset the `timer` state. Please do check it out when you've a chance. Onur's answer/solution to add another state *just* to reset the `timer` state is tending towards convoluted IMHO and is a bit of a React anti-pattern.